# Yeoman generator Error: Upstream proxy port is required

Tags: node.js, npm, yo, spfx

I am trying to create a project using yeoman generator but getting below error.

[image]

I have also tried uninstalling and installing yeoman again but its is not working. Every time I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you're in a work environment behind a proxy? If you're not sure you can check if there's a proxy configured in IE settings or by running the following command in your command line

```
    netsh winhttp show proxy
```

If that's the case, you'll need to run the following command replacing the proxy url

```
    npm config set proxy <proxy_url>
```